# RTP Stream... MPEG-2 or MPEG-4?

Tags: video, rtp, mpeg, mpeg-4, mpeg-2

I'm using RTP TS (Payload 33) to stream some video files in MPEG-2 and MPEG-4, and then perform some tasks over them.

How could I know what type of video (MPEG-2 o MPEG-4) is inside the RTP stream I receive?

Is there any header or field which indicates the one it is?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the rtsp protocol recive streaming you can check the video format of SDP(Session Description Protocol).
**ex:
 a=rtpmap:96 MP4 (96 means the payload type)**

96 in decade is 1100000 in binary so if the last 7 bits of the second byte of RTP header is 1100000 , that is point!

I just recive MPEG4 streaming so the MPEG2 you can try it use the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you don't have SDP, you can parse the packets.

If you process the PAT and PMT, you can retrieve the *stream id* for your PID from the PES header.